# Bigtable python Client: How do I retrieve the smallest rowkey that is greater than a given value

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, bigtable

I want to retrieve the row corresponding to the smallest `rowkey` that is greater than a given `value`.

How can I implement the [prefixSuccessor](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/bigtable/v1.6.0/bigtable/bigtable.go#L435) functionality that exists in the Golang client in Python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for? You will need to adapt and test this code first.

```py
def prefixSuccessor(text, num):

    # sort the text list
    text.sort(reverse=True)

    output = ""

    # loop through the list
    for i in range(num):
        output += text[i]

    return output


if __name__ == "__main__":

    # list of words
    text = ["ahty", "ghf", "hfy", "hfgt"]

    # find the length
    num = len(text)

    # print output
    print(prefixSuccessor(text, num))
```